# Does ClamAV Scan Windows virus?

Tags: 14.04, clamav, owncloud-server

I'm new to Ubuntu.

I'm now setting up an OwnCloud server which supports ClamAV file scan.

Since most of the users connected to the server uses Windows OS, can ClamAV scan for Windows virus?

I also did some research that such as BitDefender. It clams that it scans real time, if someone upload files to the server, will BitDefender scan the file even OwnCloud doesn't support?

By the way, I heard that if I update the system frequently, I don't have to install any antivirus that scan for Linux virus. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although rare, [Linux malware & viruses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware) do exist. The strict layered structure of Linux makes it however less vulnarable, but not immune. It can also not be excluded that you make a mistake, and authorize a malicious piece of software to do harmfull things.

In practice however, you will mainly use a virusscanner to protect your Windows partners. ClamAV does scan for Windows viruses as well.

Comment: So like Window Server, if I set the permissions right, update my OS usually, it is very hard to make a Linux virus works. Sounds nice.

Comment: If you are careful what to install and from where, your risk is relatively small.

Comment: As your experience, do you prefer ClamAV, Bitdefender, or Sophos (university license)?

Ahhh, seems like Sophos isn't supporting 14.04 yet.

Comment: @KKyang I think it is a matter of taste and trust, I use ClamAV, in the past I (have) used Bitdefender. Both worked fine as far as I can see, but I like the interface of (the most recent version of) ClamAV, and it is most "Linux-like". But as said, I use it mostly as a "service" for my Windows partners.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll use ClamAV, too. Cause it is officially supported by OwnCloud.

Answer (score 1):

ClamAV will scan for any viruses in it's database. The majority are Windows viruses.

There are very few viruses for Linux, and most people are safe not running anti-virus.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm so glad you reply my post so fast.
Cause this server is used as a database in my lab. Most of their PCs running Windows doesn't really care about security. So I think it might be better to install an antivirus that scan Windows viruses.